# How to make xmessage use a font?

Tags: fonts, truetype, xorg

I have properly configured fonts for X, as this shows:

```
$ xlsfonts -fn '-adobe-source code variable-extralight-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-iso8859-9'
-adobe-source code variable-extralight-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-iso8859-9
```

However passing this font to `xmessage` doesn't work:

```
$ xmessage -fn '-adobe-source code variable-extralight-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-iso8859-9' message
Warning: Cannot convert string "-adobe-source code variable-extralight-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-iso8859-9" to type FontStruct
Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion
Warning: Unable to load any usable fontset
```

I tried prepending the `xmessage` invocation with things like `LC_ALL=C` or even `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`, to no success. Has anyone achieved this? The reason I'm using xmessage (and not Zenity etc) is it's very lightweight.

Comment: I tried a lot of things and then dropped `xmessage` in favour of `Xdialog` which is also lightweight and performs great out of the box

Comment: can do, if you think that's better

Answer (score 0):

I come across your question posted a long while ago, while configuring xmessage myself. For your info, the font "-adobe-source code variable-extralight-" is not available on my system and cannot test myself. The 2 steps that may be worthwhile to do are:

(1) double-check the spelling of all the names in your -fn option against the ones listed :

`xlsfonts | grep '^-adobe-'`

(2) check xmessage does pick up the -font option with a more basic font like -*-times- :

`xmessage -font '-*-times-*-r-normal-*-18-*-*-*-*-*-*-*'  'Test Font'`

Even though I do not have the font on my system to try myself, I am sure the above 2 steps should help pinpoint the problem.

Furthermore, I would suggest testing with another adobe font:

`-fn '-adobe-new century schoolbook-*-r-normal-*-18-*-*-*-*-*-*-*'`

If this adobe font works, perhaps you have more confidence that  "source code variable" should also work.